# What is な role here?

Tags: syntax, copula

I cannot get what な means in the following sentence.

> 彼女はそれがいくら**な**のかわかります。

Couldn't it be written 彼女はそれがいくらのか分かります?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because いくら is not a verb, the の of のか cannot directly follow it; な acts to link the two.